# Retrieve sum of 5 top score from a table in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

I am working on a project where I need to extract the sum of top 5 score_rank for every team sorted in descending order from a table.
Here is the table structure

[image]

Here is the link of the structure

http://kolkata-web-design.co.in/test/structure.htm

This is the query I am trying

```
SELECT team_id AS `team` ,  (SELECT SUM(score_rank)
FROM `contest_result_total`
WHERE team = `team_id`
ORDER BY score_rank DESC
LIMIT 5
) AS `score`
FROM `contest_result_total`
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

But it does not give top 5 score instead it calculates the sum of all the contests and not just 5 grouped by team id

Can anyone help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think your GROUP BY should be within the inner query.

Comment: same results coming by adding GROUP BY in the inner query

Comment: Could you give provide the table data in a text format instead of image so that we can play around it?

Comment: ok i am giving you in data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT team_id,sum(score_rank)
FROM contest_result_total
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM contest_result_total AS c
      WHERE c.team_id = contest_result_total.team_id
        AND contest_result_total.score_rank <= c.score_rank) <= 5
GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: not giving correct result

Comment: Can you try it again, I think I had the wrong comparison in the sub query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT team_id AS `team` ,  (SELECT SUM(score_rank)
FROM `contest_result_total`
WHERE team = `team_id`
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY score_rank DESC
LIMIT 5
) AS `score`
FROM `contest_result_total`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Comment: Same thing I suggested in the comments, the OP said it does not work.